# How to Read XML Microsoft Event Logs with PHP

Tags: children

This is my First Attempt as using XML with php. what i am trying to do is find the coding to read the XML logs exported from Windows event Viewer. and i think im having issue with the Children part and learning how to read the 2 sectons. now im using a peice of code i found from the php website and still just testing it.

i can read the info from the System section but not from the next child EventData.

Thanks in advance for all of your help

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("admin/xml/events.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
if(!$xml){
    echo "No Go!";
    br();
}
else{
    echo "Good To Go!";
    br();
}

foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen) {

    foreach ($second_gen->children() as $third_gen) {
        echo ' who begot a ' . $third_gen->EventID . ';';br();


   }
   foreach ($second_gen->children() as $fourth_gen->EventData) {
            echo ' and that ' . $fourth_gen->EventID .
                ' begot a ' . $fourth_gen->Data['SubjectUserSid'];br();
        }
}
?>
```

and here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Events>
    <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
        <System>
            <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' Guid='{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}'/>
            <EventID>4656</EventID>
            <Version>0</Version>
            <Level>0</Level>
            <Task>12804</Task>
            <Opcode>0</Opcode>
            <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime='2015-04-06T19:54:07.248Z'/>
            <EventRecordID>6426</EventRecordID>
            <Correlation/>
            <Execution ProcessID='4' ThreadID='88'/>
            <Channel>Security</Channel>
            <Computer>CCS03.clearcreek.local</Computer>
            <Security/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data Name='SubjectUserSid'>S-1-5-18</Data>
            <Data Name='SubjectUserName'>CCS03$</Data>
            <Data Name='SubjectDomainName'>CLEARCREEK0</Data>
            <Data Name='SubjectLogonId'>0x3e7</Data>
            <Data Name='ObjectServer'>PlugPlayManager</Data>
            <Data Name='ObjectType'>Security</Data>
            <Data Name='ObjectName'>PlugPlaySecurityObject</Data>
            <Data Name='HandleId'>0x0</Data>
            <Data Name='TransactionId'>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
            <Data Name='AccessList'>%%1553</Data>
            <Data Name='AccessMask'>0x2</Data>
            <Data Name='PrivilegeList'>-</Data>
            <Data Name='RestrictedSidCount'>0</Data>
            <Data Name='ProcessId'>0x394</Data>
            <Data Name='ProcessName'>C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
</Events>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are incorrect:

```
foreach ($second_gen->children() as $third_gen) {
          ^^^^^^
foreach ($second_gen->children() as $fourth_gen->EventData) {
          ^^^^^^
```

Shouldn't the second loop be `$third_gen`?

Comment: here is what i get when changing that to $third_gen

Good To Go!
who begot a 4656;
who begot a ;
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a 
and that begot a

Comment: `as $fourth->EventDat` is incorrect as well... it should just be `$fourth`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to read Event Viewer from PHP, as PHP is a language uses mainly in web developments and Event Wiever is to monitor and collect details about what happens in the server, the y diese'te male se sense to work together, expose Event Viewer information to PHP can let someone read your server events, something which is aehigh risk for your server security.

For sure, your goal with this can be achieved from a different perspective with a better security, ir you explain your requirements and scope there will be people with a better approach, I don't recommend to send or read Evwnt Viewer from outside of the server without a strong security. I'm aliso happy to help you.

Comment: It is to be set up to be viewed for auditing on another system. Each day the logs are scheduled to be exported to another system and can be viewed by select users with access. Security is in mind the php scripts are run by another server. Server A(system with the event) Server B(Apache server) The system are separate and the php does not directly access the windows system. Security is in mind for this, this is noted after doing research to not have the php directly accesss the event logs but to access the exported logs

Answer (score 0):

If you can post the exportes logs it would help, although I would suggest to implement an application in the "system with the event" server reading the xml and exporting the relevant data and sending the postprocess event data to "apache server". The exported data shouldn't be a very detailed events happening in the system and I assume the Apache Server is where you want to see the events, this access should be under login/password. Hope this helps. Note that this approach is sending details from server a to server b rather than php reading events details.

Comment: Whats posted above is a copy of the export log. the proccess that im looking to create is to have my php code pull the data i need. i just cant get it to pull the section "EventData" i can pull information from System. but if there is a different software that can export for me ill take that instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are still thinking push your data, I think the problem in the code you posted is the iteration, you should iterate the events list as you already have but inside you can access to system and data directly as $second_gen->System and $second_gen->EventData, see velos and example:

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen) {
// access to variable $second_gen->System and its properties
echo 'system: ' + $second_gen->System->EventID

// also you can access to data section 
echo 'data: ' + $second_gen->EventData->ProcessID
```

}