# Read Windows Event Log with PHP

Tags: php, windows, event-log

Is there any way to read Windows Event Log with PHP?

To be specific, I want to read windows users' logon & logoff activities with corresponding user names. I am using PHP with wamp server.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517516/how-to-read-xml-microsoft-event-logs-with-php

Comment: In the link you provided they use a exported xml file. But in my case need to read event log directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to read Window's Event Log directly. But in my case I wanted have Logon & Logoff info. So I manage that in another way.

wrote two *.bat* files as follows.

**LogOn.bat**;
Which includes the following code.

```
echo Login %Date% %TIME% %USERNAME% >> {Directory path to log folder}\%Date%.txt
```

**LogOff.bat**;
which includes the following code.

```
echo LogOff %Date% %TIME% %USERNAME% >> {Directory path to log folder}\%Date%.txt
```

Then added these files to logon & logoff scripts. Bellow are the steps.

- Open "Edit Group Policy" in windows.
- Double click on "User Configuration" from the right pane.
- Double click on "Windows Settings" from the right pane.
- Double click on "Scripts (Logon/Logoff)"
- Then double click on "Logon" and add previously prepared LogOn.bat file to the container.
- Do same for the "Logoff" and add LogOff.bat.

Note; 
This will log, logon & logoff information into a file name with Day. You can change the file name as your preference.

At the end I could read the logged text files via PHP. Hope this helps to someone.